# How can I get a LT IBAN in Revolut instead of GB for my Euro account?

Tags: eur-euro, iban, brexit, revolut, lithuania

I have a €-account in my **Revolut** app that has an IBAN starting with GB (standing for Great Britain (UK)). Unfortunately the UK is not part of the European Union (EU) anymore. I've heard that some people have an IBAN starting with LT (standing for Lithuania).

How can I get an IBAN starting with LT for my **Revolut** account (for an Euro-account)?

An IBAN starting with LT would be great since Lithuania is part of the EU. I think € can be send and received without any fees for most banks within the EU. Actually I would be happy to get any European IBAN of any country within the EU in **Revolut** (does not need to be from Lithuania).

<sub>This questions is specifically about Revolut. Revolut is a banking app that lets you manage bank accounts in different countries for different currencies.</sub>

Comment: What does EU have to do with anything? Have you considered opening a bank account in Lithuania?

Comment: @littleadv From my my classical bank account I can transfer € to any other bank account within the EU **for free**. However sending € to a bank account in the UK comes with very high fees. I think similar fee-structures apply to many bank accounts within the EU.

Comment: And where are you? If you're in the UK then.... you'll have to pay the fee? Trying to understand what's so special in Lithuania and UK for you in this scenario.

Comment: @littleadv I am often in the European Union (EU). I am rarely in the UK, and if I am in the UK, I mainly pay with the local currency of the UK (GBP). I think (almost) all of my € transactions are done within the EU (€ is the main currency within the EU).

Comment: So back to my first question - what prevents you from opening a bank account in the EU instead of the UK-based bank account you have now?

Comment: @littleadv I have a bank account in the EU, but I prefer the app and the user-interface of Revolut. It is more convenient to send money to my friends via Revolut, but for that I need to transfer € from my classical EU bank account to my Revolut account. Some Revolut users have an IBAN starting with LT. I also want an IBAN starting with LT in my Revolut account for €.

Comment: Gotcha, so basically you're asking how to force Revolut to give you a specific location for your IBAN... Have you asked Revolut customer support?

Comment: @littleadv Yes, exactly. I want Revolut to give me an IBAN within the EU (e.g., an IBAN starting with LT) for my €-account.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149337/discussion-between-jakob-and-littleadv).

Answer (score 1):

You should only have a GB IBAN if you are a British resident. From what I gather from the comments you don't quite live in the UK. You should just move your Revolut account to whichever country you officially reside in, that will give you a LT IBAN. I don't know if Revolut now facilitates such move, if not you'd have to close your Revolut UK account and re-open one with Revolut in your EEA country.

Nonetheless, the UK is still part of SEPA, therefore any euro payments will still be SEPA bank transfers and will be 100% free to send and receive. Nothing has changed in this regard. The same applies for all other bank accounts within the SEPA towards GB IBANs. The CATCH is that because of Brexit the UK no longer falls under European legislation and some (not all) European banks take the freedom to apply charges to send and receive to non-EEA SEPA countries like, the UK currently is. It sucks.

If you reside in the UK, the only solution I have found so far – to be treated equally by every European bank – is using Wise, as they provide a Belgian IBAN for their euro account, even if you have a British account with them.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but apparently not only UK residents get a GB IBAN, but strangely (some) Swiss residents get a GB IBAN as well. I think in Switzerland LT IBANs would be much more reasonable for € (especially since Brexit). Thank you for the advise regarding Wise, this might be a valid work-around.